# Combat with Shadow Jaunt and Shadow Stride

Tags: dnd-3.5e, combat, tome-of-battle

First, can I use Shadow Jaunt with a move action to appear next to an enemy?

Next, can I use a standard action to attack or use a strike maneuver?

Last, can I use Shadow Stride with a swift action to move away?

All in one turn?

Does teleporting away with either the Jaunt or Stride offer an AoO?

Can I use the tumble skill to avoid it?

Would that cause the teleportation distance to halve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First, can I use Shadow Jaunt with a move action to appear next to an enemy?

No: *shadow jaunt* is a standard action. The move-action teleport is *shadow stride*.

> First, can I use Shadow [Stride] with a move action to appear next to an enemy?

Yes; why wouldn’t you be able to? Nothing in the maneuver mentions any such limitation.

> Next, can I use a standard action to attack or use a strike maneuver?

Yes; why wouldn’t you be able to? Nothing in the maneuver mentions any such limitation.

> Last, can I use Shadow Stride with a swift action to move away?

No: *shadow stride* is a move action. The swift-action teleport is *shadow blink*.

> Last, can I use Shadow [Blink] with a swift action to move away?

Yes; why wouldn’t you be able to? Nothing in the maneuver mentions any such limitation.

> All in one turn?

Yes; why wouldn’t you be able to? Nothing in any of the maneuver mentions any limitation on combining these.

> Does teleporting away with either the Jaunt or Stride offer an AoO?

This is actually unclear. “Moving out of a threatened square usually provokes an attack of opportunity from the threatening opponent.” Does teleportation count as “moving?” Unclear. Most tables seem to play that teleportation does *not* count, does not provoke.

> Can I use the tumble skill to avoid it?

Probably not; that specifies “normal movement.”

> Would that cause the teleportation distance to halve?

I guess? We’re kind of getting into ruling/houserule territory.

Comment: I'd like to point out that jaunt is a standard action, Stride is move and *blink* is swift.

Comment: @Drejzer Good point, I’ve fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

1. No, you cannot. *Shadow Jaunt* requires a standard action to use.
   (But you could use *Shadow Stride*).
2. Yes, provided you hadn't used your standard action for anything else.
3. No you cannot. *Shadow Stride* requires a move action to use.
   (Though *Shadow Blink* is a swift action.)

So you could do a *Stride* (move action) attack (standard) *Blink* (swift) but it would take 3 rounds of doing nothing to recover them all.